# Issue with javascript, IE, and shadow box

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, css

I am having shadow boxissues when I extend my side navigation in Internet Explorer only.  This is not an issue with Chrome or Firefox.  It leaves the bottom line of the site every time you change the position of the site.  Is there anyway to clear this issue, or any suggestions would be great.  The site if you want to check out the code and issue is.

http://www.rsd17.org/test/test/district1.shtml

Here is link to image to show you what I am talking about.

http://i41.tinypic.com/2m07c7.jpg

Just an update.  This only seems to be an issue now on IE 10.  Anyone know a fix?

Comment: Please try to make this posting useful for future visitors after your link is dead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix my own issue by giving my footer div a box-shadow this added to its css

box-shadow: 0 0 20px transparent;

This seems to have solved the issue.  Not sure its the best way but it works enough for me.  Thanks again for the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

[box-shadow browser compatibility](http://caniuse.com/css-boxshadow).

I'm assuming you're testing on IE 8 or lower? Please edit the question to include the version of IE you're testing on, as what it supports varies somewhat between versions.

Comment: not so much worried about it working on ie8 and lower, more worried about the lines it creates when you expand and contract the menu shown in the picture above.